# Simulating analog filter using convolution or converting with fft

Tags: fft, filters, convolution, python

My task is simple; I want to simulate analog low-pass filtering of an input signal, using Python. Note that the input signal is an array of values, not an analytical function.

My first question is if it simply is possible? If so, where is the line drawn between making a digital (FIR/IIR) filter and simulating an analog filter?

My second question is how I, in python, can make two equivalent simulations, using convolution in one, and converting the input signal to frequency domain in the other. Convolution is used in the link below, and it would help me a lot to see how exactly the same thing would be done by instead using fft (even though I think it's using an FIR filter, not simulating an analog filter).

http://glowingpython.blogspot.nl/2012/02/convolution-with-numpy.html

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What do you know about the filter that is to be implemented? Impulse response, transfer function, other specifications?

Comment: Certainly I would draw the line at doing FFT based filtering.  If you are simulating, you must want to preserve time domain characteristics and you won't do that with an FFT based approach.  When you say “simulating” what are your simulation goals?  Do you care about the filter structure?  If so you'll need to model your simulation to preserve the filter structure as well as the time domain characteristics.  So what is it that you really want to accomplish.  That will determine what simulation method is appropriate.

Comment: "Note that the input signal is an array of values"  That sounds like digital filtering to me, not analog filtering.

Comment: Hi, Deve. I want to test different kinds of analog filters, but for example a 1st-order Bessel filter.

Comment: @BZ. The main goal of my simulation is to make a simple model of a real amplifier circuit, which includes a filter. I hope to easily be able to change parameters like cut-off frequency and filter order. You say that an FFT based approach won't work. Why is that? If I take care to use a scipy built in filter command (e.g. [scipy.signal.bessel](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.bessel.html#scipy.signal.bessel), and ensure that the FFT is hermitian before using ifft, it should work right?

Comment: @endolith. In my case it's not feasible to model the input with analytical functions, so I have no choice but to create it as an array. What's not clear to me is what the fundamental difference (if any) is between simulating an analog filter and making a digital filter. In scipy you can choose to make a filter analog or digital (see [scipy.signal.bessel](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.bessel.html#scipy.signal.bessel), so I guess there is a difference.

Comment: @user4186: Note that I've been updating the docs for these functions and the more recent versions are at `/scipy-dev/` URL: [scipy.signal.bessel](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.signal.bessel.html)  Maybe that will help somewhat.

Comment: *Why* are you so intent on implementing it using FFT?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have two questions which, if answered, should give total coverage! Could anyone please help me out?
1. Am I right in thinking that using scipy.signal.bessel with analog=1 and multiplying in the frequency domain will be the most similar to the analog situation? (especially @BZ, why should not time domain characteristics preserved?)  
2. My second question in my post (fft equivalent of convolution example)

Comment: No, multiplying the signal's frequency spectrum with the analog filter's frequency response and inverse transforming will not work, since the filter's response to the end of your signal will wrap around and mix with the beginning of your signal, called "time domain aliasing".  Do you understand this?

Comment: Convolution filtering is a type of FIR filtering, and you're talking about deriving the FIR filter by sampling the frequency response of the analog filter, which means the frequency response *between* your samples will not be correct.  See [Frequency Sampling Method for
FIR Filter Design](http://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Frequency_Sampling_Method_FIR.html) and [Frequency Sampling Method](http://nrlug.puhep.res.in/GLUE/Packages/engg/DSP/book/node134.html).  To reduce this effect, you use lots of zero padding, which is a trade-off similar to my method of oversampling and using IIR filters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What's not clear to me is what the fundamental difference (if any) is between simulating an analog filter and making a digital filter.

Either way, these functions will produce "ba" transfer function outputs, but the b and a are totally different.

For a 2nd-order filter, for instance, b = [b0, b1, b2] and a = [a0, a1, a2].  These are the coefficients of the transfer function.

For an analog filter, this represents a transfer function like this:

$$H(s) = \frac{b_2 s^2 + b_1 s + b_0}{a_2 s^2 + a_1 s + a_0}$$

For a digital filter, the transfer function is:

$$H(z)=\frac{b_0+b_1z^{-1}+b_2z^{-2}} {a_0+a_1z^{-1}+a_2z^{-2} }$$

> Note that the input signal is an array of values

Then you are doing digital filtering.  You can *simulate* analog filtering this way, but it's only going to be a simulation.

All the [Python IIR filter functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/signal.html#matlab-style-iir-filter-design) you're talking about, when outputting a digital filter, design it as an approximation of the analog filter using an analog filter transfer function prototype and then converting it to digital using the [bilinear transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform) and [frequency warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform#Frequency_warping).  Yes, they can output analog transfer functions, but I think that's only useful for building actually analog electronic filters, or for plotting the [frequency response](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.signal.freqs.html), [impulse response](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.signal.impulse.html), etc.

The Bessel in particular is a bad approximation as you get near fs/4, because the important property of a Bessel filter is group delay, not amplitude, and phase/group delay is not preserved by the bilinear transform (red vertical line is fs/4):

[image]

[More plots of digital Bessel filter](https://secure.flickr.com/photos/56868697@N00/tags/besselfilter/)

You can make the simulation closer to what an analog filter would produce by putting a large margin between the highest frequency in your signal and the sampling frequency, called [oversampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oversampling).  Assuming your "array of values" is correctly bandlimited, then you can upsample them and then apply the digital filter using [lfilter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) and the ba digital filter coefficients you found earlier.  If not, you need to bandlimit the analog signal and then sample it at a significantly higher rate.  How did you get your sampled signal?  If you are generating it digitally, it is probably not bandlimited, unless you specifically thought of bandlimiting while generating it.

> for example a 1st-order Bessel filter

All 1st-order filters are the same, the "1st-order Bessel" is the same thing as a "1st-order Butterworth" or anything else.

Comment: Thanks for a very good answer! Currently I'm generating the input array within the python script, so I'll make sure to have significant oversampling. Also, currently I'm mostly interested in noise performance, so the phase response is of less importance. Currently I'm transforming the input to frequency domain, multiplying it with the filter frequency response and finally transforming back to time domain. Is that equivalent to using lfilter or filtfilt? Also, how could I use convolution to reach the same result?

Comment: @Uffe: How are you generating the signal, though?  Is it bandlimited?  How are you calculating the frequency response?  You can do filtering using frequency-domain multiplication, time-domain convolution, or using a direct filter implementation.  All of these can be made to produce identical output, I believe, but there are implementation details.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Without going into too much detail, I'm generating something like a square wave but with changing amplitude levels. Then I add noise using 'random.normal'. I simply use fft to get the freq response. To convert back to time domain, however, I make sure to have hermitian symmetry. Finally I need to be able to reconstruct the original voltage levels. It seems to me that using fft and multiplying with the vector plotted to the left in your picture should give a very close estimation of applying an analog filter. This should avoid the fs/4 problem I guess. Do you agree?

Comment: @Uffe: I'm guessing your "square wave" is not bandlimited? (switching between amplitudes is not good enough: http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/307/week5/bandlimited.html and https://gist.github.com/endolith/407991) So when you generate it at a higher sampling rate, it will still not be bandlimited (square waves have infinite harmonics and your "oversampling" would just include more of them). Still, the higher in sampling frequency you go, the better approximation of analog you get, so I'd use `lfilter` and heavy oversampling. Increase the sampling rate until you don't see changes in output.

Comment: @Uffe: And no, multiplying by FFT will not simply give you the same output.  FFT is for cyclic signals, so the tail end of your filter's response would wrap around and mix with the beginning of the signal.  With zero-padding and thinking about causality, I think it's possible to produce the same output as lfilter, but why bother when you can just use lfilter?  Are you concerned about making this simulation as fast as possible?

Comment: True, the signal is not bandlimited. So far, simulation time is not important. The reason I'm still considering fft, is that it seems to closer resemble an analog situation. My thinking is that after fft, I can choose the analog approximation of the Bessel filter (left in your picture). With lfilter I guess I don't have that choice. I don't think aliasing is a problem, since my I choose my filter to have as many vector elements as the input signal (no downsampling is made). In other words I simply attenuate certain frequencies of the input signal.

Comment: @Uffe: Unless you've specifically generated your signal in a bandlimited way, then it's not bandlimited and it is aliasing.  Assuming the frequency content drops off at higher frequencies, oversampling will reduce the effects of aliasing.  The IIR filter *is* an approximation of the analog filter, and will be more and more accurate the higher the oversampling rate.  As long as your sampling rate is far higher than the fc of the Bessel filter, it will be just like the analog filter: http://flic.kr/p/e6VZYF

Comment: If I was starting with a analog signal I would agree with you, but here I simply start with generating the array (so perhaps I was wrong in saying that the signal was not bandlimited). The array is of course finite and can therefore only contain a finite amount of frequency components (up to fs/2). Another way of looking at it could be to perform fft on the array, then inverse fft. The result will be exactly the same as the original array, without aliasing.

Comment: @Uffe: If you were generating an array of a sinusoid, then it would be bandlimited, but if you are generating an array of a waveform with infinite harmonics, then it is not bandlimited.  It is like taking an ideal mathematical square wave and sampling it without putting it through an antialiasing filter first.  Any harmonics above fs/2 are aliased back down below fs/2, etc. Additive synthesis of only the harmonics below fs/2 can avoid this, or oversampling can reduce its effects.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. Any aliasing affects below the cutoff frequency of the filter I later apply will stay in the signal if I don't bandlimit my initial array. That is a difference compared to the analog situation which I'm trying to simulate. For simplicity I think I will use a high degree of oversampling. Thanks!

Comment: @Uffe : Are you after any further clarification?

Comment: @PeterK.: Yes, see my last comment under the question (perhaps I should have put it here instead)

Answer (score 1):

> Q1. Am I right in thinking that using scipy.signal.bessel with analog=1 and multiplying in the frequency domain will be the most similar to the analog situation?

What you get from `scipy.signal.bessel` with `analog = 1` will be the continuous-time transfer function (assuming you want the `ba` version of the output).  You will have to be careful to make sure you're doing the right sort of filtering: just using FFTs to simulate this will probably not work correctly.

I'm **not** an expert in `python`, but I suspect you want to use [`scipy.signal.freqs`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.freqs.html#scipy.signal.freqs) to get the *continuous* frequency response.

The trouble then is: how do you get the *continuous* frequency response of your input signal?  Do you now how your analog input signal vector was generated?

**EDIT**

So reading the scipy manual, I see [`lsim`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lsim.html#scipy.signal.lsim) or [`lsim2`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lsim2.html#scipy.signal.lsim2) are probably the options you want. It appears to allow you to apply a continuous-time system to data sampled at given sample points.

> Q2. ... how [can] I, in python, can make two equivalent simulations, using convolution in one, and converting the input signal to frequency domain in the other

To do the convolution, you could just use [`scipy.signal.impulse`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.impulse.html#scipy.signal.impulse) to get the impulse response of your filter, and then use [`scipy.signal.convolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html#scipy.signal.convolve) to convolve it with your sampled data.

To get the frequency domain version, you'll again need to understand how your analog input signal vector was generated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding Q1, I can try to make my question specific. The picture in answer 1 above compares an analog freq response with a digital one. I assume that by using normal digital filtering (using e.g. [lfilter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html)) filtering will be made as seen in the right plots. If I instead transform to freq domain, and use the response seen to the left, I should get a closer approximation to an analog filter (assuming that I convert back to time domain correctly). Am I correct in this?

Comment: Regarding Q2, also here to be specific, how can I make an exactly equivalent filtering, as seen in the [link](http://glowingpython.blogspot.nl/2012/02/convolution-with-numpy.html), but transforming to freq domain, and do the calculation there, instead of using convolution? (perhaps someone skilled in python can help here)

Answer (score 0):

I need something similar in Python but I can't understand what's wrong...

1. creating simple 1th order low-pass Butterworth filter, Fc=10Hz

```
# creating I order, 10 Hz, low pass Butterworth filter
fc = 10 # [Hz]
wc = 2*np.pi*fc # [rad/s]
b, a = signal.butter(1, wc, 'low', analog=True) # mi ritorna un sistema Num(s)/Den(s)
num=b
den=a

w, h = signal.freqs(b, a)   # ideal frequency response of filter
w = 0.5*w/np.pi             # [rad/s] to [Hz]
amp=20*np.log10(np.abs(h))  # amplitude to dB

'''
# ideal filter frequency response dB vs Hz
plt.plot(w, amp)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel("Frequency [Hz]")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude [dB]")
plt.show()
'''
```

2. get impulse response

```
system=signal.lti(num, den)
t, impulse_resp = signal.impulse(system)
impulse_resp = impulse_resp[1:]     # removing first element due it's always 0.0
t = t[1:]

print("Risposta impulsiva:")        # filter impulse response (kernel of filter in time domain)
print(impulse_resp)

# normalizing kernel to 1.0
kernel=len(impulse_resp)
impulse_resp=impulse_resp /sum(impulse_resp)    # vado a normalizzare il kernel per il filtro
print(sum(impulse_resp))
```

3. creating white noise

```
# let's make some noise
mu, sigma = 0, 0.1
sample = 100000         # 100k samples
Fs=1000                 # [SPS] sampling frequency
x = np.arange(sample)
noise = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, len(x))  # noise

# time domain to frequency domain (noise)
#f, psd = signal.periodogram(noise, Fs)
f, psd = signal.welch(noise, Fs, scaling='spectrum')

# removing first element due related to 0 Hz (for log scale)
f=f[1:]
psd=psd[1:]
```

4. filtering in time domain using convolution and filter impulse response

```
# filtering in time domain using convolution and filter impulse response
filtrato=np.convolve(noise, impulse_resp)   # filtering noise
filtrato=filtrato[:len(filtrato)-len(impulse_resp)+1]   # equalizing length due to kernel dimension

# time domain to frequency domain for filtered noise
#f, psd2 = signal.periodogram(filtrato, Fs)
f, psd2 = signal.welch(filtrato, Fs, scaling='spectrum')

# as above
f=f[1:]
psd2=psd2[1:]
```

5. amplitude spectrum ratio to get filter frequency response

```
# ratio filtered/unfiltered signal
legenda=[]
tf=psd2/psd
plt.plot(f,20*np.log10(tf))
legenda.append("real")
plt.plot(w, amp)
legenda.append("ideal")
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('Attenuation [dB]')
plt.legend(legenda)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Is this right or am I doing something wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to DSP.SE! Your **answer** does not actually answer this question because it is a question itself. As such, please ask your intended question in a separate post in which you can link to this post for reference!