# Formula for Bessel low-pass filter coefficients

Tags: lowpass-filter, python, infinite-impulse-response

When I am filtering a signal in python, it has a built in [function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.bessel.html) to generate bessel filter coefficients given a cutoff ratio and a filter order (number of poles). I am trying to translate this to C code, but I cannot seem to find the formula that is used to calculate the coefficients.

Can someone point me to the formulas to calculate the IIR filter coefficients given a cutoff ratio and order?

I am trying to read the scipy source on github but I am having a very hard time of it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Looking at the source code for `scipy.signal.bessel`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/signal/filter_design.py#L2351), you're out of luck for finding a formula: they don't use one.

They just have a big `if` \ `elif` sequence for various values of filter order:

```
if N == 0:
    p = []
elif N == 1:
    p = [-1]
elif N == 2:
    p = [-.8660254037844386467637229 + .4999999999999999999999996j,
         -.8660254037844386467637229 - .4999999999999999999999996j]
elif N == 3:
    p = [-.9416000265332067855971980,
         -.7456403858480766441810907 - .7113666249728352680992154j,
         -.7456403858480766441810907 + .7113666249728352680992154j]
elif N == 4:
```

[The Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_filter#Bessel_polynomials) has some formulae for Bessel filters in the continuous domain:
$$
\theta(s) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k s^k
$$
where
$$
a_k = \frac{(2n-k)!}{2^{n-l}k!(n-k)!} \mbox{ for } n = 0,1,\ldots,n.
$$
To get discrete-time near-equivalents, you'll need to do a continuous-to-discrete transformation. Note that this will not necessarily preserve the nice phase properties of the continuous-time Bessel filter.

Comment: I don't mind using a lookup table for my own code. I need to dig through the rest of their code to figure out to transform for a given cutoff. Those arrays are for the general case and have not yet been shifted for a given cutoff, I think.

Comment: Yes. I haven't looked at that code in detail, but usually a unit cutoff is assumed for the general case.

Comment: @KBriggs The frequency shifting is done in the function called `_zpklp2lp` in that source code.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to pull out the relevant parts of the scipy code, so I now have my own functional python implementation. Translating it to C is going to be a bit of a pain because of the complex numbers, but it all looks doable.

Comment: Actually you're looking at an outdated version.  I rewrote it in Sept 2015 https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/402b8f3fe0264d1b80eede12bf71be3ce6d30177  You have to look at the "master" branch to see the latest code.

Comment: I added my own answer :D

Answer (score 4):

Hi, I wrote this.  It's probably more complicated/inefficient than it needs to be. :D

Practical Bessel filter design involves root-finding of a polynomial to generate second-order sections; I don't believe there is any simple formula.  The way SciPy stores filter coefficients is pole and zero locations, so the code finds these locations numerically.

The steps I originally used are:

1. Generate the coefficients of a [reverse Bessel polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_polynomials)
2. Find the roots of the polynomial (= poles of the Bessel filter) using the [Aberth-Ehrlich method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberth_method)
3. Scale the poles inward or outward to normalize either the -3 dB frequency, phase, or group delay.

Step 2 generates approximate roots from [Campos-Calderón 2011](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.0957) as the starting points for the root-finding, but I don't know if that's really necessary.  Most root-finding algorithms just use asymmetrical starting points on a spiral, etc. and still find the answer fine.  I assumed it would be faster this way.

Aberth-Ehrlich is good for quickly finding multiple single roots simultaneously, by modelling them as point charges that repel each other, so multiple test points don't fall into the same holes.

Eventually I ended up eliminating Step 1 altogether.  For the Newton's method part of Aberth-Ehrlich, it actually evaluates $K_{n+\frac 1 2}\left(\frac 1 x \right)$  instead, which is a totally different (compiled) function that has the same roots, and has a relatively simple derivative.  This is possibly crazy and less efficient than it could be, but it works.  ([`kve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.special.kve.html) is actually [`zbesk`](http://netlib.org/amos/zbesk.f) from AMOS Fortran library.)

$\theta_{5}(x)$ vs $K_{5.5}\left(\frac 1 x \right)$:

[image: Complex plot of 5th order reverse Bessel polynomial, with amplitude as lightness and phase as color] [image: Complex plot of 5.5th order modified Bessel function of 1/x, with amplitude as lightness and phase as color]

Then in step 3, I don't even use the Bessel polynomial to normalize the function, since I eliminated the need for all but the last coefficient and it's faster to just generate that one by itself.

There's also this algorithm I found later, which could probably be made more efficient: [Orchard 1965 - The Roots of the Maximally Flat-Delay Polynomials (Bessel filters)](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1082473/) though it has some numerical error at high N and doesn't give an algorithm for finding the new approximate roots from the old (just "eyeball it on graph paper").

But now you can generate 500th order Bessel filters with 3 different normalizations, instead of just reading the coefficients from a table (not that you would ever need to...):

[image: Poles of a 500th-order Bessel filter]

Comment: these are $s$-plane, right?  at normalized $\omega$?

Comment: also, i imagine transforming this with the bilinear transform does not preserve the flat group delay (or flat phase delay) at higher frequencies, does it?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Yes, S-plane.  No, bilinear doesn't work well unless cutoff frequency is very low.  I also started implementing Thiran filters (Digital equivalent) but never submitted it.

Comment: so the $z$-plane filters that have maximally-flat group delay are called *"Thiran* filters"?  seems to me that they're APFs.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Yes, digital all-pole maximally-flat delay LPF: http://upir.ir/aban93/5_77d0e.pdf More commonly transformed to allpass filters, though? https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Thiran_Allpass_Interpolators.html (I wrote this section:) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_filter#Digital

Comment: oh, you did!  Julius farmed out a section of his book?  (or you mean Wikipedia?)

Comment: the wikipedia section. just a disclaimer that it doesn't have any more claim to truth than my comments do :)

Comment: oh, i don't think either of us would write anything untruthful in either Wikipedia or SE.  :-) $$ $$ and i've got the scars (from Wikipedia and from the Christianity.SE) to show for it.  funny, i was fighting atheist POV-pushers at Wikipedia and Christians at the SE page.  both groups seem to highly overestimate their own objectivity.

Comment: i have to confess that, while i knew of Bessel filters and knew that frequency-warping of the bilinear transform would mess up either the group delay or phase delay of what **was** flat in the Bessel filter, i had not known of what was a classic design of a recursive $H(z)$ having flat delay as did the Bessel filter.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! If you're curious, my C port is here: https://github.com/shadowk29/CUSUM/blob/master/bessel.c

Comment: @KBriggs You saw the above discussion about Thiran filters, right?  You shouldn't use bilinear-transformed Bessel unless the cutoff is significantly below fs/4 https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/8420/29 I do have a working Thiran filter design function, but I need to clean it up a lot and convert it to using poles/zeros natively before putting it in SciPy.

Comment: Interesting, I missed that. My applications generally have cutoffs below fs/4, but only just. How significantly is needed?

Comment: @KBriggs That's up to you :)  Plot the group delay and see if it's good enough for your application.  It will curve upward near the cutoff frequency instead of being maximally-flat

Comment: I suspect it won't matter too much, but I'll look into it to be sure. Thanks for the heads up, that's new information for me. I'll look into Thiran when it hits scipy :)

Comment: @endolith - late followup: if I use a non-causal filter (python filtfilt, specifically) does the phase distortion caused by the bilinear approximation disappear?

Comment: @KBriggs `filtfilt` turns any filter into a zero-phase filter, yes.  Since the whole point of Bessel is causal flat group delay, there's not much reason to use it with `filtfilt`

Comment: @endolith - thanks. I mostly wanted to check if filtfilt would allow one to use fc=fs/4 and avoid the distortion there.

Comment: @KBriggs Well the rule of thumb is fc < fs/4, which you can always achieve by upsampling the signal first.  `lfilter` vs `filtfilt` doesn't have anything to do with that.  If you want constant-delay digital lowpass filters look at Thiran filters, though.  I have an unfinished implementation here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/compare/master...endolith:thiran_filters?expand=1  If you bother me about it I'll finish it.  :D

Comment: @endolith anything I can do to help?